# LibGDX frame drop

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making Android game in libGDX, I am using ShapeRenderer and very little SpriteBatch. There are about 5-10 rectangles on screen.

Sometimes (about every 30 seconds) there is FPS drop from 60 to 40 which lasts about 10 seconds. And it is very distracting, therefore I believe that only few frame renderings are very slow Problem is that I cannot realize what is the reason of these drops.

Of course, I believed that problem is in memory management, but I tracked memory usage via Android Profiler and GC is not called at that moment.

I would like to post some code, but I really have no idea which part of code can be useful for resolving issue.

Does anybody have any idea what might cause that problem?

This is deltaTimes, and FPS drop occurs together with those error messages. It looks like this is audio problem.
[image]

One more error message after which FPS is normal again.
06-01 16:27:48.151 419-419/? D/SurfaceFlinger: Backpressure trigger, skipping transaction & refresh!

Comment: You should post the code that gets executed each frame.

Comment: Well, there are several classes, it is not beginning of development. The point is that game logic and rendering are not complicated and that they should execute without any problems.

Comment: How do you know they execute without any problems? Do you still get the frame drops if you just draw an empty scene?

Comment: Well, I want to say that there is obviously problem but I would say that those objects don't cause it. State of game with FPS drop is not different from state of game without FPS drop. And that FPS drop occurs periodically.

Comment: Look at updated post.